# Android SDK Manager and Android Studio disagree about the SDK path... What do I do?

Tags: android-studio

So I had Android SDK Manager install the android SDK here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`

Now I install Android Studio, and it wants to know where it should put the SDK. So I pointed it to the same place, thinking there's no need to have the SDK in two places. It complains that there can be no spaces in the path.

Why does SDK Manager allow (even recommend a path with) spaces, but AS doesn't? Do I need to delete and reinstall the SDK in, say, `C:\Android`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try escaping the path, in Windows, it's done with a caret.

```
C:\Program^ Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

Or put quotes around the path

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"
```

But I'll suggest moving it to a path without spaces. Same goes for any programming project that involves paths because spaces are just an inconvenience.